# Problems bundling React Native iOS app using CocoaPods

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

I am building an app using https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase and it suggested the best way to install is via CocoaPods, however, I am getting 10000 problems, one after the other when I try and archive my app.

I am wondering what is best practice when using React Native and Cocoapods and how things are imported/loaded and if it is CocoaPods which is actually affecting my app.

I have eventually got to this step, and it runs in the Simulator, however I am unsure if I need all my references to different pods in my even though i might of installed them via `npm install`.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated as I feel like abandoning CocoaPods all together and trying to install from scratch.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Add yoga.
  # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13046#issuecomment-350523190
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Set React to be from node_modules.
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport',
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTNetwork',
  ]

  target 'myApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    # pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-video'

    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

    pod 'SentryReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sentry'

    pod 'react-native-in-app-utils', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-in-app-utils'

    pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

    pod 'RNIap', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-iap'

    # pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'

    pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  end

  target 'myApp' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: The doc itself doesn't recommend using Cocoapod for React Native Firebase. Great that you switched from that. Please post any issue in particular that you are facing.

Comment: @Vishu RNFirebase state that Firebase suggest using CocoaPods to install Firebase. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios#1.3.-Install-Firebase-Library

Comment: Very true @Karl, but at the same time it dosen't recommend the using CocoaPods for RNFirebase.

Comment: @Vishu I do not understand what you are saying. The docs clearly recommend in section 1.3 https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios#1.3.-Install-Firebase-Library to use Option 1: Cocoapods (Recommended). Please refrain from posting incorrect and unuseful information.

Comment: in the same page if you look down at '2. React Native Firebase Installation Recommended installation' section, it clearly doesn't  recommend using CocoaPods for RNFirebase.

Comment: @Vishu You are correct, but you are looking at the wrong thing. To install the Firebase Library, it recommends Cocoapods. You're talking about the `react-native-firebase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a big resounding **yes**. CocoaPods **does** cause problems with a React Native App.

After commenting out most of the other Pods. My application built fine first try and uploaded to app store.

My advice. Do not add stuff to CocoaPods if you do not need to.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myApp
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  # pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  # pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  # pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Add yoga.
  # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13046#issuecomment-350523190
  # pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # # Set React to be from node_modules.
  # pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  #   'Core',
  #   'DevSupport',
  #   'CxxBridge',
  #   'RCTNetwork',
  # ]

  target 'myApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    # pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-video'

    # pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

    # pod 'SentryReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sentry'

    # pod 'react-native-in-app-utils', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-in-app-utils'

    # pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

    # pod 'RNIap', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-iap'

    # pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'

    # pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  end

  target 'myApp' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end

end
```